# Hibernate create database every time run the project

Tags: hibernate

I have running a project in hibernate and the connection and pojo classes are successfully created for me. Now my problem is when i have running a project each time the hibernate is trying to create the database in the connected host, that's why unwanted indexes in my database each time when i run the project. Anybody know how could i avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your hibernate config, from this

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

to this

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

To stop hibernate creating the database each deploy.  Alternate options are [also available.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/106261)

Comment: But i have only <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> this in my hibernate config file

Comment: then hibernate is not creating a database, it is only altering it

Comment: Then how i got create multiple indexes in my database. Is there any other config to change?

Answer (score 0):

change your hibernate config, from this

create
to this

update

The DB will create 1 time